# Put images gallery vertically instead of horizontally in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

First I want to warn you, I am pretty new to HTML so forgive me in advance if I am asking stupid questions ! 
I have started this class where we need to create our own website and they teach us how to create a simple images gallery but only horizontally. However, in order to create a better design for my website, I'd like to create an image gallery but vertically. How can I do? I have seen few answers elsewhere but we haven't learnt any complicated stuffs yet so I did not understand a thing !
Here is what I wrote on my HTML document:

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://media.mq.edu.au/mas240/js/gallery.js"></script>

</head>

<section>

<img src="images/th-dancestudio2.jpg" class="gallery" href="images/dancestudio2.jpg" />

<img src="images/th-dancestudio3.jpg" class="gallery" href="images/dancestudio3.jpg" />

<img src="images/th-dancestudio4.jpg" class="gallery" href="images/dancestudio4.jpg" />

<img src="images/th-dancestudio5.jpg" class="gallery" href="images/dancestudio5.jpg" />

</section>
```

Here is what I wrote on my CSS document:

```
.gallery {
float: center;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 5px solid black;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such property as `float: center;` use `display: block` if you want to have them display vertically.

Like so:

```css
.gallery {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<section>

<img src="images/th-dancestudio2.jpg" class="gallery" href="images/dancestudio2.jpg" />

<img src="images/th-dancestudio3.jpg" class="gallery" href="images/dancestudio3.jpg" />

<img src="images/th-dancestudio4.jpg" class="gallery" href="images/dancestudio4.jpg" />

<img src="images/th-dancestudio5.jpg" class="gallery" href="images/dancestudio5.jpg" />

</section>
```

If you want the images centered or aligned to the right just use the `text-align` property

Comment: Thank you it worked ! However it stays in the middle of the page. If I am not able to use float which property do I have to use to position the gallery to the left or right of the page?

Comment: `float: left;` or `float: right;` or `text-align: left;` or `text-align: right;`

Comment: If I use `float:left;` it puts back the gallery horizontally and `tex-align: left` doesn't do anything :/

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks again but by using the `text-align` property the gallery becomes horizontal again :/

Comment: Look at my answer, I've added `text-align: right;` and the images are aligned to the right. You must have some other code messing with this I suppose.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking too ! I'll go through everything and check ! Thank you again for your help !

Comment: Cheers! if this answer is good please accept it and vote up, thanks.